# AlertDialog is not dismissed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the following code to show an alert dialog to open the Locations Service Settings :

```
alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
alert.setTitle("Unable to Retrieve Current Location");
alert.setMessage(" Enable Location Service ?");
alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Open Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        alert.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
});
alert.setCancelable(false);
alert.show();
```

The settings opens normally but when I press back then the Previous dialog is not dismissed.   How to dismiss the dialog when back in from settings.

Comment: in `onResume` of your `previous Activity` call `alert.dismiss();`

Comment: replace alert.dismiss() with dialog.dismiss in your onClick()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder (context);
alert.setTitle ("Unable to Retrieve Current Location");
alert.setMessage (" Enable Location Service ?");
alert.setButton (DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Open Settings", 
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
    context.startActivity (intent);
  });

// Create and show the dialog.
alert.create();
alert.show();
```

Main differences are postponing *create* till after you add the components, calling *show*, and not calling *dismiss*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `alert.dismiss();`

On click Event

try `finish();` // This will finish your Activity

Answer (score 0):

Use `dialog.dismiss();` instead of `alert.dismiss();`